# Git apply doesn't create new files?

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to create patch by `diff` and `apply` it. My patch has new file and after `apply` I'm getting an error.

```
git diff master origin/master > patch1.diff
git apply patch1.diff -v

Checking patch test3...
error: test3: No such file or directory
```

Patch:

```
diff --git a/test3 b/test3
deleted file mode 100644
index df6b0d2..0000000
--- a/test3
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-test3
```

What I'm doing wrong or `git apply` doesn't create new files?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `git format-patch`?

Comment: Yes, a common interest)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're creating your patch backwards - that patch is trying to *delete* that file.  I think you wanted:

```
git diff origin/master master > patch1.diff
```

You might find `git format-patch` to be helpful.  If you currently have `master` checked out, you can just do:

```
git format-patch origin/master
```

That command will yield a bunch of patch files, one for each commit different between your branch and `origin/master`.  You can then apply those using `git am` and retain all of the extra data like commit message and author information.

Comment: It's even more convenient if you use the `--stdout` option. `git format-patch --stdout origin/master | pbcopy` puts the patch on my clipboard (OS X) and `pbpaste | git am` will apply it to the current repo.